# PyQt5: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have installed Python 3.7.1 and trying to run a form created using QTdesigner.But this error occurred.I have also installed PyQt5 module using

```
pip install PyQt5
```

The error is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets   

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python and pip seem to be running on different versions.

If you're using various versions of Python,  use 
    `python -m pip install PyQt5`
instead of `pip`.

Comment: pyqt5 version:5.11.3 is installed for python 3.7.1.Is it proper..?

Comment: I'm clueless that PyQt5 is available on Python 3.7. Testing in Python 3.6 is also a good way.

Answer (score 3):

I have used all the below mentioned commands having done it with both VS terminal and cmd:

```
python -m pip install pyqt5
pip3 install pyqt5
python -m pip.py install pyqt5
```

Although it did install correctly but when I import PyQt5.QWidgets i get an error stating module not found.
I am saying it did install correctly because when I run these commands again get a message "Requirements already satisfied".

Answer (score 2):

You can use pip3 to install a python3 module:

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :
Check your python directory correctly installed or Not.
**Go to** the below a directory by cmd and run the commands.

```
C:\Users\PC_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>

pip install PyQt5
```

your `PRO.py` program now ready to run successfully.

Comment: This worked! Thanks!
Note: \Python37-32\ is referring to your Python version, in case you made the same mistake as me lol. You can also do 'dir' and see the Python(#) folder

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your pycharm is configured to use virtual environment. Try installing PyQt5 from pycharm terminal. It will install PyQt5 in your virtual environment and it fixed the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when starting with PyQT5. Do not know if this might answer your question but here was my scenario. I had both python 2.7 and python 3.7 on my machine. My pip 2.7 was added to the path instead of the 3.7. So i removed python 2.7 from the path, reinstalled python 3.7 and added to the path and restarted. After that used pip to install pyqt5 and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by using `python -m pip install PyQt5` on windows not `pip install PyQt5`

Comment: This absolutely works as of February 2022. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by uninstalling the pip version and instead installing from apt:

```
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```