# pyinstaller ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtNetwork'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm using conda to handle my environment. Previously I was running my qt application using X11 forwarding from my linux box without any import issue, but I wanted to test performance with a bundled executable on Windows, so I tried using pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w .\main.py
```

I set up my conda environment with the following (note pyqt is installed in the environment). I originally tried to export my linux conda environment without build numbers to windows, but conda did not seem to be able to resolve the environment. I directly installed these dependencies:

```
altgraph                  0.17.2             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bottleneck                1.3.4            py39h080aedc_0
ca-certificates           2022.4.26            haa95532_0
certifi                   2021.10.8        py39haa95532_2
cffi                      1.15.0           py39h0878f49_0    conda-forge
future                    0.18.2           py39hcbf5309_5    conda-forge
icu                       58.2             vc14hc45fdbb_0  [vc14]  anaconda
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_0    anaconda
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0    anaconda
macholib                  1.16               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h277e83a_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hf11a4ad_0
numexpr                   2.8.1            py39hb80d3ca_0
numpy                     1.21.5           py39h7a0a035_2
numpy-base                1.21.5           py39hca35cd5_2
openssl                   1.1.1o               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.4.2            py39hd77b12b_0
pefile                    2021.9.3           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pip                       21.2.4           py39haa95532_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pycryptodome              3.14.1           py39hb82d6ee_1    conda-forge
pyinstaller               4.8              py39h8cc25b3_0
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py39hd77b12b_6    anaconda
python                    3.9.12               h6244533_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywin32                   303              py39hb82d6ee_0    conda-forge
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0           py39hcbf5309_1005    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0  [vc14]  anaconda
setuptools                61.2.0           py39haa95532_0
sip                       4.19.13          py39hd77b12b_0    anaconda
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sqlite                    3.38.3               h2bbff1b_0
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2              py39haa95532_2
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
zstandard                 0.17.0           py39hb82d6ee_1    conda-forge
```

When I run pyinstaller without the `-w` option, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "client.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtNetwork'
[19256] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Line 4 of `client.py` is the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWebSockets
```

Am I not importing/installing pyqt correctly? I'm running pyinstaller after conda activating my environment. I can't seem to find this specific error elsewhere with pyinstaller. It's normally the entire pyqt5 module that is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works, but it does for my situation:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --hidden-import PyQt5.QtNetwork .\main.py
```

I was referencing this SO: [PyQt5: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460186/pyqt5-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyqt5)